# In Collections, how can i get the index using the indexOf method in the following example

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, indexof

```
    class Fruit{
      public String name;
      Fruit(String name){
        this.name = name;
        }
    }//end of Fruit

    class FruitList{
     public static void main(String [] arg5){
        List<Fruit> myFruitList = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
        Fruit banana = new Fruit("Banana"); 
    //I know how to get the index of this banana
        System.out.println("banana's index "+myFruitList.indexOf(banana));
 //But i'm not sure how can i get the indices for the following objects
        myFruitList.add(new Fruit("peach"));
        myFruitList.add(new Fruit("orange"));
        myFruitList.add(new Fruit("grapes"));
  }//end of main 

}//end of FruitList
```

Since the rest of the objects that i've added to the ArrayList have no references, i'm not quite sure how their index can be retrieved. Please help, Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6):

It does not matter which reference the object has if you redefine the equals and hashcode methods in the Fruit class. `indexOf`, `contains`, etc use the `equals(...)` method to decide if the object exists inside the collection.

For example, your Fruit class, could be like this (I changed your `public String name` to private):

```
public class Fruit {
    private String name;

    public Fruit(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Fruit other = (Fruit) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Then:

```
Fruit f = new Fruit("orange");
myFruitList.indexOf(f); // this should return the orange fruit index (would be 1 in your example).
```

Comment: Could you please add an example? I am really interested in it (Example which solves the problem), i could think only about iteration through list and to get the indexes of each object where it's name field corresponds to searched one.

Comment: I think OP didn't understood your solution, what's why he didn't accepted the answer.

Comment: I don't know why, he did not reply anymore. If he still have some questions, he can write in these comments, I guess he is offline :/

Comment: @Fernando Garcia, thanks for the answer but all i wanted to know was how could i have got the index for this object-
  myFruitList.add(new Fruit("peach"));
***I mean- specifically in this case- the object isn't referenced anywhere, so if i were to make use of indexOf method how can i get the index

Comment: The doing `myFruitList.indexOf(new Fruit("peach"));` would return you the index if you created the `hashCode` and `equals` methods that i wrote above.